# Write regular expresiond and find finite automata

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata

I am learning about finite automata and regular expressions, but I cannot find solution to a problem, so I'll be thankfull if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

The problem is:

Write regular expression and find finite automata that have the same number of 1 and 0 and there isn't word prefix that has difference between the number of 1 and the number of 0 bigger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

This automaton has the state set $S=\{B,E,+1,+0, F0,F1\}$. The inputs are $0$s or $1$s the outputs are also $0$ or $1$. The automaton is waiting in state $B$ and in state $F0$ it gives the output $0$ signaling that difference between the zeros and the ones coming in is $2$ the first time. In state $F1$ it gives the output $1$ signaling the other meaningful event.

The state transition function is given by the following graph.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But what is with the condition that there IS NOT a prefix of the word that has the difference between the number of zeroes and ones bigger than 1? @zoli

Comment: @silent_rain: Then I did not understand that part perfectly. Pls. give an example. Like 01010100?? This is word with the prefix: 010101. The current version exits after the second zero coming after the prefix. Please give an example and tell me what would you like the automaton do.

Comment: Prefix 010101 is OK, it has the same number of ones and zeroes and the difference between the number of zeroes and ones is 0 that is less than 1.. 

But, I thought that your word is with prefix 0100 or 1011. Maybe I don't understand your picture.. :(   @zoli